# $S_n$ and its subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that $A_n$ is unique in $S_n$ with index $2$.

I'm trying to use Quotient Group and Lagrange's Theorem to approach this problem but I'm still clueless. Can anyone tell me how to do this problem? Thanks.

Comment: A subgroup of order 12 in $S_4$ would be normal. Suppose that $N$ is a different normal subgroup of $S_4$. What can you say about $A_4\cap N$?

Comment: Is this for n $\geq$ 5, or just in general? For n=1,2,3,4, this can be done explicitly.

Comment: in general I think.

Comment: @IanColey why would a subgroup of index 2 be normal?

Comment: $A_1$ is trivial, as is $A_2$. Any index two group in $S_3$ must have order 3. We only have two elements of order three in $S_3$ and they generate each other. For $S_4$, I would need to think for a moment.

Comment: @user93383 **Hint:** (To prove index 2 implies normal.) There are only two cosets. One contains the identity. How does this imply that left and right cosets are equal?

Comment: The extended theorem is that if the index of a subgroup is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group, then the subgroup is normal.

Comment: ...and it has to be the smallest prime as, for example, $S_3$ contains no-normal subgroups of index three (so order two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I comment above, for n=1,2,3,4, this can be done explicitly. Assume n $\geq 5$. We know that any index 2 subgroup must be normal (Quite easy to show). Let N be another subgroup of $S_n$ of index two. Then both $A_n$ and $N$ are normal, so the intersection $A_n \cap N$ is also normal (in $A_n, N$ and $S_n$). But, since $A_n$ is simple, this means that $A_n \cap N=\{1\}$. So, $|A_n \cup N|=n!-1$. So there is a single nonidentity element of $S_n$ not in either of our index two groups, call it $x$. Any normal subgroup is the union of conjugacy classes (of $S_n$ here). So $x$ lies in its own conjugacy class of $S_n$, and hence lies in the center of $S_n$. BUT, the center of $S_n$ is trivial. Contradiction. $x$ cannot be in the center.